# Proof that $H$ is subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Good evening,

Let $ G = \mathbb{Q}^2$ \ $ \{(0,0)\} $
with $ (x_1,x_2)*(y_1,y_2) := (x_1 y_1 - x_2 y_2 , x_1 y_2 + x_2 y_2).$
I have shown that $G$ is an abelian Group with a neutral element $ e= (1,0)$
and and inverse $b= ( \frac{x_1}{x_1^2 + x_2^2 }, \frac{-x_2}{x_1^2+ x_2^2}).$

Now I have to show that $$H_2= \{(x,0) \ |\  x \in \mathbb{Q}  \backslash \{0\}\} \cup \{(0,x) \ | \ x \in \mathbb{Q} \backslash \{0\}\}$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

$H_2$ is a subgroup if $ e \in H_2$ and $ x,y \in H_2 \implies xy^ {-1} \in H_2$

I don't understand how I can show these attributes for the union. Can someone maybe please make an example?

Comment: What does $\Cup$ mean?

Comment: just the usuall U for Union. \Cup in Latex.

Comment: The most straightforward way to do this is to make four different cases according to which of the two sets $x$ and $y$ belong to. In fact $G$ is the multiplicative group of nonzero complex numbers with rational real and imaginary parts. $H_2$ is the subgroup of elements of $G$ that are either real or purely imaginary. But it looks like you're supposed to do this problem as if you hadn't noticed that. You may also find it a bit simpler to do this for products $xy$ and inverses $x^{-1}$ separately, rather than $xy^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

The group $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}, \cdot$ by the map $(x,y)\mapsto x+iy$. Then $H_2$ corresponds to $\mathbb{Q}\cup i\mathbb{Q}$. Can you now conclude that this is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it:

If $x=(x_1, x_2), y= (y_1, y_2) \in H_2$ then

either $x_1= y_1 = 0;$ and $x_2 \ne 0; y_2 \ne 0$ so $y^{-1} = (\frac 1{y_1},0)$ and $xy^{-1} = {\frac xy,0} \in H_2$.

or $x_1 = y_2 = 0$ and $x_2 \ne 0; y_1 \ne 0$ and $y^{-1} = (0, -\frac 1 {y_2})$ and $xy^{-1}= (0, -\frac x{y_2} ) \in H_2$.

or $x_2 = y_1 = 0$ etc. or $x_2 = y_2 = 0$etc.